# Passing JSON over .ajax() with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm having trouble understanding how to create a jQuery .ajax function to post data (multiple variables) to my php page, then return the information from the PHP page.

```
$('#RoomCode').change(function() 
{
    //alert($(this).attr('value'));
    var RoomCode = $(this).attr('value');

    //Create JSON Object to send to Ajaxdo
    var toAjax = { "GetRoomCodeParams": [ { "GetRoomCode" : "1", "RoomCode" : RoomCode } ]};
    alert(toAjax);
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "ajaxdo.php",  
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: json,
        cache: false,        
        data toAjax,
        success: function (response) { 

            alert(response);
            $('#RoomInfoCode', '#RoomClassCode').fadeOut();     
            $('#RoomInfoCode').empty();
            $('#RoomInfoCode').fadeIn();    

        } 
    });    

});
```

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out the missing colon : (now appended to code)

now i receive missing }  after property list success: (response) {}

i have since cleared ammended success to the following, and still receive this error:

```
success: function (response) { }
```

Comment: you need a ':' after data prop ;)

Comment: that took care of that problem. now i get missing { after property list success: function (response) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
data toAjax,
```

should be

```
data: toAjax,
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out a colon, try

```
data:toAjax,
```

rather than

```
data toAjax,
```

Comment: any idea why im getting this other error?